# message: undefined variable in view

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get the data in my view in codeigniter but it gives me a Message: Undefined variable: topics_array

*here is my model :*

```
public function studentTopics($courseId, $periodId)
{
    $this->dbi->select('topicitem.TopicItemID, topicItem.Content');
    $this->dbi->from('topicitem, topics, periods');
    $this->dbi->where('topics.PeriodItemID', $periodId)
            ->where('topics.TopicItemID = topicitem.TopicItemID')
            ->where('topics.PeriodItemID = periods.PeriodItemID')
            ->where('periods.CourseID', $courseId);
    $res = $this->dbi->result_array(); 

    return $res;
}
```

*here is my controller*

```
public function student_topic($courseId, $periodId)
{
   $this->load->library('table');  
   $this->load->model('Student_model');      
   $data['topics_array'] = $this->Student_model->studentTopics($courseId, $periodId);  
   $this->load->view('Student/StudentView', $data);
}
```

*and my view*

```
<?php
  $courseID = $this->uri->segment(4);
  $periodID = 1;
  foreach ($topics_array as $key =>$value) {
       echo "<tr> 
             <td>".$value['Content']. "</td>
             </tr>"; }?>
```

Comment: that's really strange as you are doing it correctly. even if the query were to fail you'd get either null or an array so something would happen. are you sure its undefined variable and that you are using the above code? any typos in your version where you assign the var? can you `var_dump($data['topics_array']);` after `$data['topics_array'] = $this->Student_model->studentTopics($courseId, $periodId);`

Comment: it is $res = $this->db->result_array();  not $res = $this->dbi->result_array();

Comment: ^ assuming they have assigned a certain database globally via `dbi`. in any case undefined variable wouldn't be the result. query error or unable to locate method would be the error.

Comment: The var_dump doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `get()`.

```
$res = $this->dbi->get()->result_array(); 

return $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you :

change this line of code : `$res = $this->dbi->result_array();`

```
$this->dbi->select('topicitem.TopicItemID, topicItem.Content');
$this->dbi->from('topicitem, topics, periods');
$this->dbi->where('topics.PeriodItemID', $periodId)
        ->where('topics.TopicItemID = topicitem.TopicItemID')
        ->where('topics.PeriodItemID = periods.PeriodItemID')
        ->where('periods.CourseID', $courseId);
$query = $this->dbi->get(); // missing this line of code

$res = $query->result_array();
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data